# Click on a URL from an R string output

Tags: r, string

Suppose I have an output from the cat function of R which is a URL. For example:

```
cat("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics")
# Output: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics
```

Is there any command on the cat function or any other thing so that the output https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics becomes a clickable URL in the R console?

Comment: in the R console?

Comment: @BigDataScientist Yes, clickable in the R console.

Comment: are you using RStudio, would be the viewer pane (on the right of the console) be an option for you?

Comment: @BigDataScientist Yes, I'm using RStudio.

Comment: ...and would the viewer pane (on the right of the console) be an option for you to display the links?

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned in the comments you are using RStudio. It is not specified why it has to be the console in R, but I assume there is a good reason to display the links within RStudio and I assume the viewer pane on the right next to the console also works for you.

If that is the case you could do the following:

```
library(DT)    # for datatable() function
library(shiny) # for tags$a() function
data <- data.frame(link = toString(tags$a(href = paste0("http://google.de"), "google")))
datatable(data, escape = FALSE)
```

Very close to the console ;)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using package `cli` you can get a clickable URL directly in the console:

```
cat(
   cli::style_hyperlink(
      text = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics",
      url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics"
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on how the output is being viewed. If this output is going to an HTML file, then all you need to do is set this as the location for a hyperlink.

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics</a>
```

But if, for example, you are just viewing the output in notepad, then I don't believe notepad has the functionality for hyperlinks.

I don't believe the R console directly supports hyperlinks or not. But it looks like from this: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-2.html that you can maybe use R Markdown to do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

This is not currently possible in RStudio, unfortunately. However, it is an [open issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2530) which you can upvote if you think it should be prioritised.