# Generate a link in R in a sentence

Tags: r

While creating a vector  in R, can we make the links are highlighted. For example,

```
vector1 <- "This is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611862/url-generation-in-shiny\"
```

This is the vector

Expected output

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923974/click-on-a-url-from-an-r-string-output

Comment: No this is the not the one. This does not differentiate between text and url . For example ````http://google.com This is the link````. Here only first string is link and then it is a text

Comment: You need to explain why you need this. You shouldn't care about having clickable links in the R console. If you do care, you should probably create a notebook using markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from [Tonio Liebrand's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923974/click-on-a-url-from-an-r-string-output):

```
library(DT)    # for datatable() function
library(shiny) # for tags$a() function

vector <- data.frame(link = paste0("This is the link: ",
                                 (toString(tags$a(href = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611862/url-generation-in-shiny/","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611862/url-generation-in-shiny/")))))

datatable(vector, escape = FALSE);
```

You will find a clickeable link in Viewer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that but the link is not clickable:

```
library(crayon)
v <- paste0(
  "This is the link ",
  blue("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611862/url-generation-in-shiny")
)
cat(v)
```

You can also underline:

```
v <- paste0(
  "This is the link ",
  blue(underline("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611862/url-generation-in-shiny"))
)
cat(v)
```

In fact you can create a hyperlink:

```
v <- paste0(
  "This is the link ",
  hyperlink(
    text = blue(underline("Click here")),
    url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611862/url-generation-in-shiny"
  )
)
cat(v)
```

But this is not supported by the RStudio console:

```
has_hyperlink()
# FALSE
```

Otherwise, you can get a clickable link in the RStudio viewer:

```
library(htmltools)
browsable(
  tags$p(
    "This is the link: ", 
    tags$a(
      href = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611862/url-generation-in-shiny",
      "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611862/url-generation-in-shiny"
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But do i have to follow this everytime. Can we not automate this? Because, you are manually adding a url here

Comment: @user11740857 Everytime of what? You have a vector of urls? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Yeah your right. I have vector of url. Sorry my bad

Comment: @user11740857 So do a `for` loop. What's the problem?